# I want give alias to jquery builtin function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to rename the built in function of jquery like for ajax i want to replace It with MyAjax function I call also call it will its previous name.

```
$MyAjax();

$.ajax();
```

So i want to call in this way. it can be possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

Is this you want to do.

```js
var $MyAjax = $.ajax;

var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

$MyAjax({
  url: root + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He asked for $MyAjax as the variable name but this seems to answer his question +1